# Difference between equal operator and is operator in enums

Tags: c#, enums, c#-9.0

Given the following `enum`,

```cs
enum ExampleOptions
{
  OptionA,
  OptionB
}
```

Is there any real difference between these two statements?

```cs
ExampleOptions option = ExampleOptions.OptionA;

bool equals1 = option == ExampleOptions.OptionA; // true
bool equals2 = option is ExampleOptions.OptionA; // true
```

As far as I can see, the only difference between using `==` and `is` is mainly that `is` expects a constant operand (thus, operation order matters).

> I used to use the `==` operator just because I wanted to avoid ugly statements such as
> `!(option is ExampleOptions.OptionA)`.
> But, after C#9 was released and the `is not` operator added; I find `is`/`is not` a cleaner and more verbose way to write this kind of statements.

Is there any hidden consequence of deciding which operator to use?

Comment: The `==` uses the equality operator which could be overloaded for classes or structs, although for enums that's not possible in `c#`.

Comment: `is` is used as part of pattern matching: it just so happens that `ExampleOptions.OptionB` is a very simple pattern. I'd try and stick with `==` for the simple cases, just so that people reading your code (including you in the future) know that it's a simple comparison, and don't need to start looking for patterns

Comment: Shouldn't `equals2` be `false` instead of `true` since you compare `OptionA` to `OptionB`?

Comment: @juharr [and it is ....](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCABBk)

Comment: Yeah, @juharr Sorry. That was a typo.

Comment: @canton7: Actually the `is <constant>` expression is more lightweight than the `==` operator and the in the dotnet/runtime repo a lot of `== null` comparisons have been replaced to `is null`, for example. The latter is always just a reference comparison, while `==` considers the possible operator overloads as well.

Comment: @canton7 I'd like to stick always with the same syntax (as much as possible), even for simple expressions. `option is ExampleOptions.OptionA` seems pretty readable and clean to me, although.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg Right, replacing `== null` with `is null` makes sense for various reasons. That's an exception though, and I'm not talking about that: I'm talking about replacing `== <some value>` with `is <some value>`.

Comment: Note that patterns can only work with **constant** values: you can't write `someTimeSpan is TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)` or something. You need to use `==` for almost all equality comparisons *anyway* (unless you plan to spend you programming career only comparing things to consts), so `==` is the de-facto equality comparison, like it or not. Using `is` just for enums and built-in types, and `==` everywhere else, is inconsistent and confusing IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for enum comparisons `is` seems syntactic sugar.

```
bool equals1 = option == ExampleOptions.OptionA; // true
bool equals2 = option is ExampleOptions.OptionA; // true
```

Both statements compile to exactly the same IL (tested in .NET5), they invoke the CIL instruction `ceq`, which I think stands for equality comparison.
So your assumption that there is no functional difference seems correct.

```
// [115 13 - 115 61] 
IL_0003: ldloc.0      // option
IL_0004: ldc.i4.0
IL_0005: ceq
IL_0007: stloc.1      // equals1

// [116 13 - 116 61]
IL_0008: ldloc.0      // option
IL_0009: ldc.i4.0
IL_000a: ceq
IL_000c: stloc.2      // equals2
```

Comment: I have already checked a couple of scenarios in [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/) and I found the same. I was wondering if there was any case this changes. But it seems there is none. And yeah, [`ceq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq?view=net-5.0) is the op code that checks for equality. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> As far as I can see, the only difference between using == and is is mainly that is expects a constant operand (thus, operation order matters).

There's quite a few more differences, for example `is` allows you to write statements like:

```
val is ExampleOptions.OptionA or ExampleOptions.OptionB or ExampleOptions.OptionD
```

rather than the old fashioned statement with `||` and repeated naming of your variable.

`is` also (and this is very important!) doesn't call `operator ==`, it directly checks the instance. This doesn't apply to enums, but if you have an object with a user-defined `==` operator that doesn't check for `null`, `var != null` will most likely crash with an exception, while `var is not null` will do as you expect.

Comment: Yeah! I have already read about the *use `is not null` instead of `!= null`* warning. My question was more focused on the *enum* comparison scenario. But your point about being able to make more complex expressions makes sense, thank you!